# display:none - other options

Tags: html

I have in my form a listbox, encapsulated within a span, which i want to hide but i also want the listbox to be generated because i have a javascript code which reads the options inside that listbox and display the values as a string.

When i use

```
<span style="display:none">listbox code </span>
```

I notice that my js code reading the contents of the listbox does not work.
I also read the following on the w3school `display:none: the element will generate no box at all`.

Is there a way of hiding the span while generating the listbox??

In  fact i want the listbox to act as a hidden field and thought about hiding it using the display function

Thanks for any suggestion provided.

Code added:

```
 <span style="display:hidden">
    <select size=5 id="submission_person_ids" name="submission[person_ids][]"  onfocus="displayPersons();"> </select>
  </span>
```

Comment: What do you mean with listbox? Can you show that code?

Comment: Why not use a hidden field then? I'm not sure I understand. What do you want to do, can you show some code?

Comment: I am using a popup to populate the listbox found in my form but my boss does not want to see the listbox, he wants a string of values. I kept that listbox to make things simpler when saving the form

Comment: Changing `display` doesn't remove an element from the DOM. Just because it's not shown doesn't remove it from the document. It's just not visible. Your code to get at the element must be faulty, as `document.getElementById('submission_person_ids')` would work regardles of display or visibility settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't intend to show an input, you should use a <input type="hidden"> instead and manipulate it's value.

Inputs which are hidden with display:none, or inside a hidden container, will be parsed into the DOM, but will not be submitted, which I assume is the source of your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use

```
visibility:hidden;
```

but this will leave space of the exact dimensions of the input put making wierd spaces.
To overcome that. You will need to style your elements as `position:absolute` to the parent and `z-index` it and set the width and heights for cross browser compatibility.

`Display:none`  is like the browsers does not render it anywhere virtually. When you call display:block..etc it actually renders in the browsers and computes all the new styles.

But like @Gerry said

use  `<input type="hidden">`

if you want to hide some variables on the page- Then using jquery and the `.show()` you can access data from the hidden inputs and populate the displayed element